# Cannot run the Arc samples

Tags: arcobjects

When I try to compile I get

Error   1   Cannot register assembly "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\DynamicBiking\CSharp\bin\Debug\DynamicBiking.dll" - access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator. Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DynamicBiking.BikingTrackModeCmd' is denied.  DynamicBiking2010

Trying to compile this one: 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/SampleZips/101efef5-9071-49ac-9ce9-c5a5fe5cc896CSharp.zip

I have administrator priveleges

Comment: If you're running under Windows 7, I wouldn't try to compile things from your desktop. That might lead to problems. Try compiling in a directory off of root to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the shortcut for your development environment and 'Run as Administrator'

Comment: I don't that option when I right click

Comment: @iterationx Try holding down the shift key prior to right-clicking the shortcut. Also, make sure that you're right-clicking on devenv.exe (and not a link to it) to ensure that the "Run as" option is available.